# How can I add alternate tags to my multilingual site in Hugo?

Tags: seo, technical-seo, hugo

I am designing a multilingual site with Hugo CMS, but I need to add  tags between the headings to make it SEO compatible. I have 2 different languages and I want to add the default language feature.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Hugo, to specify the `<link rel="alternate">` code in the `head.html` section, firstly

Open the `layouts/partials/head.html` file path and then paste the following code between the `<head>` codes:

```html
{{- if .IsTranslated -}}
    {{ range first 1 .AllTranslations }}
    <link rel="alternate" hreflang="x-default" href="{{ .Permalink }}" />
    {{- end -}}
    {{ range .AllTranslations }}
    <link rel="alternate" hreflang="{{ .Language.Lang }}" href="{{ .Permalink }}" />
    {{- end -}}
{{ end }}
```

Comment: I'll try it right away

Comment: Thank you, it worked, should I use the multilingual /en /ru in this hugo or should I install it in the main directory as /ru?

Comment: it's entirely your decision.